# Print the length of maximum subsequence of '1' s

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, sequence

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Motu
 {
    // Returns length of the longest subsequence
    // of the form 0*1*0*
    public static int longestSubseq(String s)
    {
        int n = s.length();
 

       
        int[] count_1 = new int[n + 1];
        count_1[0] = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
         {
            count_1[j] = count_1[j - 1];
            if (s.charAt(j - 1) != '0')
                 count_1[j]++;
         }
          
        // Compute result using precomputed values
        int ans = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            for (int j = i; j <= n; j++)
                ans = Math.max(count_1[j] - count_1[i - 1] , ans);
                               
        return ans;
     }
 
    // Driver code
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String s =sc.next();
        System.out.println(longestSubseq(s));
    }
}
```

I am trying to make a program to get maximum sequences `1` in a string containing `0's` & `1's`. But I am unable to make out the logic for it, my program prints a number of 1's in the string which is not my desired output.

```
Sample input:- 0011100111100
output:- 4
```

Comment: You should iterate for each character when you find a 1 you start counting when you find a zero you should reset the counter and update a "max" variable if the new count is higher than the previous count.

Comment: Your comments are not related to the code. For example there are no pre_count_0 and post_count_0 variables. In any case I suggest to simplify your code. Try to imagine how you would solve this problem in your mind. Do you need to know the length of all subsequences of zeros to know what is the most long sequence? I suppose not because  You can do that also with a sequence of 1000 digits and you don't store in your mind each subsequence length of zeros. So try to apply the same logic in your code. The code will be a lot easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

You're quite good, but you're missing one thing : if the char is `'0'` : reset the counter to zero

```
for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
    if (s.charAt(j - 1) != '0')
        count_1[j] = count_1[j - 1] + 1;
    else
        count_1[j] = 0;
}
```

---

But that can be done in one loop only, count with an `int`, and keep track of the max

```java
public static int longestSubseq(String s) {
    int ans = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (c == '1')
            count++;
        else
            count = 0;

        ans = Math.max(ans, count);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: @azro thank u for suggestion ,i have added else statement to reset to counter to 0.The program is working fine

Comment: @ScaryWombat keep track of the longest subsequence ?

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static int longestSubSequence(String str, char ch) {
    int res = 0;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        count = str.charAt(i) == ch ? count + 1 : 0;
        res = Math.max(res, count);
    }

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the other answers that work with a for-loop:

You could split the sequence into groups of ones with regex. Next, just iterate over the groups and update the count, if the length of the group is bigger than the previous length.

The first group will be `111` and the next one `1111`. Thus the count will first be 3 and then it will be updated to 4.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class CountSubsequence {
     public static void main(String []args){
        String sequence = "0011100111100";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(1+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sequence);
        int count = 0;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            int currentLength = matcher.group().length();
            if (currentLength > count) count = currentLength;
        }
        System.out.println(count); // 4
     }
}
```

Since regex is not that performant you might want to use the for-loop in case you care for performance - but that just matters if you  execute it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The input string may be split by the characters that are *not* `1` (thus all non-1 characters are ignored and subsequences containing only 1 remain), and then the max length of the remaining parts can be found using Stream API:

```java
public static int longestSubSequence(String str, char ch) {
    return Arrays.stream(str.split("[^" + ch + "]"))
                 .mapToInt(String::length)
                 .max()
                 .orElse(0);
}
```

Similarly, a *matching* pattern can be created, and the max length of the group can be found:

```java
public static int longestSubSequence(String str, char ch) {
    return Pattern.compile(ch + "+")
            .matcher(str)
            .results()
            .map(MatchResult::group)
            .mapToInt(String::length)
            .max()
            .orElse(0);
}
```

Test:

```
System.out.println(longestSubSequence("00111011001111", '1')); // 4
```

It's worth mentioning that the characters other than `'0'` and `'1'` may be present in the input string, only subsequences of the given char are counted.